# Purpose of double angle brackets on the bash command line?

Tags: bash, command-line

I'm trying to understand the following command:

```
user$ bash < <(curl -s https://something.com )
```

What do the `< <` do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not `< <` but first `<` which means input redirection and then `<( ... )` which means run the command inside the braces and make from that a file argument.

This looks to me quite equivalent as

```
curl -s https://something.com | bash
```

Comment: In this context, the two are essentially the same (executing the script downloaded from the website - should be fun!).  However, you can use multiple 'process substitution' commands, and still use regular standard input if you so desire: `cat >>xyz - <(cmd1) <(cmd2 -o opt1 arg1)` (so `cat` is run with three arguments and reads standard input and the output from each of the two commands).

Comment: Looks to me a convoluted way to do `(cat; cmd1; cmd2 -o opt1 arg1) >> xyz`

Comment: In the specific case of `cat` - yes.  In a more general case of a command that does different things with different files, it can be useful to have the output of a process treated as a filename argument on the command line.  Not all that often, but very useful when it fits the need.

Comment: Sure. There are cases where this syntax is useful. For example some commands insist not having passwords passed as arguments for obvious security reasons but allow them to be passed through files. eg: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19656-01/821-1509/dsadm-1m/index.html . It is quite easy to simplify their use in scripts by avoiding the file like this `--pwd-file <(echo secretPassword)`

Comment: Is there any official reference about `<(command)` and `>(command)`?

Comment: There is no official reference as the feature isn't backed by the POSIX standard. However, you'll find many references about this syntax in ksh, bash and other shell documentation. It is named "process substitution" and first appeared in ksh in 1988. It was later implemented by bash and other shells. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49918/when-was-process-substitution-first-introduced